# NavNodeEntry component dropdown is returning every item type

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I'm trying to connect a link component to a `CMSNavigationEntry`. In backoffice;

CMSNavigationEntry -> Administration -> Component

[image]

As seen in the picture the component dropdown is trying to return all the items (2.416.622 in stage environment), which is a very large amount and results in a long loading screen. I only want CmsComponent or CMSLinkComponent types to appear in the dropdown area. How can I achieve this?

I'm using hybris version 1905.